# How to parse String data from xml dom parser?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using XMLparser WS.so I get below kind of data in response.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">

     {"DBVersionList":[]}

 </string>
```

I want to parse above data and need only {"DBVersionList":[]} this as value.

I tried as below code.

```
    Document doc = xmlparser.getDomElement(response); // getting DOM
    NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
    Log.e("Log","value="+n2.item(0));
```

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: I updated my question ,what i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer of my question.

```
    Document doc = xmlparser.getDomElement(response);
    Element element=doc.getDocumentElement();
    element.normalize();
    Log.e("Log","Value="+element.getTextContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

you coud write like this, ok , there must be at least 30 characters

Comment: where has to atleast 30 character?